# Core Data sort descriptor with comparator

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have an entity model like ...

```
[Event]<--->>[Invite]<<--->[Person]
```

I'd like to create a `NSSortDescriptor` on this so that if an `Event` has any `Invite` where the `Person` is equal to a given person then they will come first.

i.e. If there are 5 events and one of them has an invite to the current user (which I pass in) then the one with the invite will be first followed by the remaining four.

At the moment I'm just displaying them in `date` order but I'd like to create an `NSSortDescriptor` for this.

I'm thinking it should use `sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:` where I specify the comparator but what key should I use? `invites`?

Comment: Is this going to run on entities in memory or in the store (SQL limitations)?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not actually sure. This is the first time I've used anything more than just a key for a CoreData NSSortDescriptor. I was just going to add this to the sortDescriptors array of a NSFetchedResultsController request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:` with an FRC because the sort will be performed in SQL on the store itself and there's no way to convert the block into SQL. You also can't use transient variables.

I'd think about having 2 sections to the results (and therefore 2 different fetch requests with different predicates) and sort each individually. The predicate then deals with the user information and the sort is simple (by date as you currently have it).

Comment: Ah, OK, I see. Will have a go at this. Thanks.